# geth Core question, why does pending transaction only returns for local accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum

in pending Transaction (eth_pendingTransactions) why is it the node is checking for only those transactions which the sender/from came from the accounts a node is managing(created/keystore,etc).

Im referring to this line in the code
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/13bc9c0c6e74f36f6f8039d0041fb93740d25a4a/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1805

Does it return an issue when say i need to query pending transactions in the chain using another node? right now i am getting only the transactions from accounts local to a node instead of all pending transactions.

Comment: I guess it is because it would be very expensive to check accross the entire network if someone has a transaction from a specific address.

Comment: I don't remember the `eth_pendingTransactions` api, it is not mentioned on the [old wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API/80562f72a9091830ada2e2e91219678e30155bf7). To get the pending transactions you used `eth.getBlock('pending')` or under geth the txpool api.